# Mistakes in solving linear combination $A cos(z) + B sin(z) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

So with some Google I found that I can write this linear combination as

$$C \sin(z + \phi) = 0$$

for $\phi = \arctan{A \over B}$. That gives us

$$z = n\pi + \arctan{A \over B}$$

for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

However, in my original attempt, I wrote this equation as:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A(\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}) + B(\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}) &= 0 \\
(A + \frac{B}{i})e^{iz} + (A - \frac{B}{i})e^{-iz} &= 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Here I can do it in two ways. The first gave me a wrong result with the term $\arctan(B/A)$, whereas the second gave me the correct $-\arctan(A/B)$.

The first method uses $1/i = -i$. We obtain

$$
\begin{aligned}
(A-iB)e^{iz} + (A+iB)e^{-iz} &= 0 \\
(A-iB)e^{2iz} &= -A - iB \\
e^{2iz} &= \frac{-A -iB}{A - iB}
\end{aligned}
$$

For the second, multiply both sides by $i$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(iA+B)e^{iz} + (iA-B)e^{-iz} &= 0 \\
(iA+B)e^{2iz} &= -iA+B \\
e^{2iz} &= \frac{-iA+B}{iA+B}
\end{aligned}
$$

If I then took $\mathrm{Log}$ on both side, the first will give me:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Log}(e^{i2z}) &= \mathrm{Log}(-A-iB)-\mathrm{Log}(A-iB) \\
i2z - 2ik\pi &= \ln(\sqrt{A^2+B^2}) + i\mathrm{arg}(-A-iB) - \ln(\sqrt{A^2+B^2}) - i\mathrm{arg}(A-iB) \\
i2z - 2ik\pi &= i\arctan(\frac{-B}{-A}) - i\arctan(\frac{-B}{A}) \\
i2z - 2ik\pi &= i\arctan(\frac{B}{A}) + i\arctan(\frac{B}{A}) \\
z &= \arctan(\frac{B}{A}) + k\pi
\end{aligned}
$$

The second will give me:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Log}(e^{i2z}) &= \mathrm{Log}(-iA+B)-\mathrm{Log}(iA+B) \\
i2z - 2ik\pi &= \ln(\sqrt{A^2+B^2}) + i\mathrm{arg}(-iA+B) - \ln(\sqrt{A^2+B^2}) - i\mathrm{arg}(iA+B) \\
i2z - 2ik\pi &= i\arctan(\frac{-A}{B}) - i\arctan(\frac{A}{B}) \\
i2z - 2ik\pi &= -i\arctan(\frac{A}{B}) - i\arctan(\frac{A}{B}) \\
z &= -\arctan(\frac{A}{B}) + k\pi
\end{aligned}
$$

I have numerically checked the first result, and it is off by $\pi / 2$, which is not surprising given $\arctan(x) + \arctan(1/x) = \pi / 2$.

My question is, in which step did I make a mistake? All transformations seem valid to me.

Comment: Wow.    take $u_1 = \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}  $  and  $u_2 = \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}  $ There will then be some $w$    such that $\cos w = u_1,  \sin w = u_2.$  When $A,B$  are real we may take $w$ real.  then.....

Answer (score 2):

So the problem lies in the fact that $\mathrm{Arg}(x + iy) = \mathrm{atan2}(y, x) \neq \arctan(y / x)$. According to Wikipedia, this holds only when $x > 0$:

$$\displaystyle \operatorname {atan2} (y,x)={\begin{cases}\arctan \left({\frac {y}{x}}\right)&{\text{if }}x>0,\\[5mu]\arctan \left({\frac {y}{x}}\right)+\pi &{\text{if }}x<0{\text{ and }}y\geq 0,\\[5mu]\arctan \left({\frac {y}{x}}\right)-\pi &{\text{if }}x<0{\text{ and }}y<0,\\[5mu]+{\frac {\pi }{2}}&{\text{if }}x=0{\text{ and }}y>0,\\[5mu]-{\frac {\pi }{2}}&{\text{if }}x=0{\text{ and }}y<0,\\[5mu]{\text{undefined}}&{\text{if }}x=0{\text{ and }}y=0.\end{cases}}
$$

In the first method, we have $\mathrm{atan2}(-B, -A)$ and $\mathrm{atan2}(-B, A)$, we can't simplify them, as $-A$ and $A$ are of different signs.

For the second approach, we have $\mathrm{atan2}(-A, B) -\mathrm{atan2}(A, B)$. We can check the three cases:

1. $B > 0$, we have $\mathrm{atan2}(-A, B) - \mathrm{atan2}(A, B) = \arctan(-A/B) - \arctan(A/B) = -2\arctan(A/B)$.
2. $B < 0$ and $A > 0$, we have $\mathrm{atan2}(-A, B) - \mathrm{atan2}(A, B) = \arctan(A/B) - \pi - (\arctan(A/B) + \pi)$, we get an extra $-2\pi$ that gets cancelled by periodicity.
3. $B < 0$ and $A > 0$, same as above except we get $2\pi$.